# Removing duplicate substrings within a string in C#

Tags: c#

How can I remove duplicate substrings within a string?  so for instance if I have a string like `smith:rodgers:someone:smith:white` then how can I get a new string that has the extra `smith` removed like `smith:rodgers:someone:white`. Also I'd like to keep the colons even though they are duplicated.

many thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep the colons for the strings that were removed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
string input = "smith:rodgers:someone:smith:white";
string output = string.Join(":", input.Split(':').Distinct().ToArray());
```

Of course this code assumes that you're only looking for duplicate "field" values. That won't remove "smithsmith" in the following string:

```
"smith:rodgers:someone:smithsmith:white"
```

It would be possible to write an algorithm to do that, but quite difficult to make it efficient...

Comment: And don't forget that you can omit the `ToArray` call if you're using .NET4.

Comment: @LukeH:  Why don't you need the `ToArray()` call?

Comment: @Odrade: In .Net 4, string.Join is overloaded to accept `IEnumerable<string>`.  In .Net 3.5 and earlier, it is not.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx .

Answer (score 8):

Something like this:

```
string withoutDuplicates = String.Join(":", myString.Split(':').Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: Can never remember the String.Join() method much as I try to remember it. You don't need the <string> on the ToArray().

Comment: You don't need the type parameter on ToArray(), but otherwise spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the format of that string:

```
var theString = "smith:rodgers:someone:smith:white";
var subStrings = theString.Split(new char[] { ':' });
var uniqueEntries = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in subStrings)
{
    if (!uniqueEntries.Contains(item))
    {
        uniqueEntries.Add(item);
    }
}

var uniquifiedStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in uniqueEntries)
{
    uniquifiedStringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}:", item);
}

var uniqueString = uniquifiedStringBuilder.ToString().Substring(0, uniquifiedStringBuilder.Length - 1);
```

Is rather long-winded but shows the process to get from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you want to keep the duplicate colons. if you are expecting the output to be "`smith:rodgers:someone::white`" try this code:

```
    public static string RemoveDuplicates(string input)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection unique = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        string[] parts = input.Split(':');
        foreach (string part in parts)
        {
            output += ":";
            if (!unique.Contains(part))
            {
                unique.Add(part);
                output += part;
            }
        }
        output = output.Substring(1);
        return output;
    }
```

ofcourse i've not checked for null input, but i'm sure u'll do it ;)